# how to update style properties in <style> tag using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to update style properties for some element **not inline** but in  tag. here is html example

for example i want to update .container element padding which is already specified in  tag **without touching other styling properties**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

  <title>Example HTML</title>
  <style>
    .container {
      padding: 5px;
      background-color: brown;
      color: white;
      position: absolute;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">Container Element</div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: any reason why you want to change that with javascript instead of just adding a new class with the new value to the property?

Comment: @theospace — Modifying the element in the DOM to set its inline style is something the question explicitly rejected and your code wouldn't work anyway because `getElementsByClassName` doesn't return an element.

Comment: @Dejan.S --- there are lots of style properties including Media Queries so it gets messy if it's inline and adding class names would cause the element to have a very long className

Comment: You are free to do as you like but I would say what you want to do is not a common or good practise. In my 10+ years as a dev I haven't worked with any project where we even thought of this, because of reasons I mention before. There is no problem with long classnames. You mention media queries, are you suppose to add that with js as well? You are complicating something so easy way too much.

Comment: ok man.. thanks for your help . I'll try using classnames instead.